# How to attach a title to a data frame in R?

Tags: r

I want to add a title to my report using R. 
Basically i have a data frame containing the values like below and a character variable having value as "demand report".

```
report_name <- paste("Demand Report")
> class(report_name)
[1] "character"

demand_vals <- as.data.frame(demand_vals)
print(demand_vals)
    x   y
    item 1  172
    item 2  153
    item 3  159
    item 4  199
    item 5  179
```

I want to append both the above and give an output like this:

```
**Demand Report**   
x   y
item 1  172
item 2  153
item 3  159
item 4  199
item 5  179
```

Is this something possible in R?

I was trying to do a rbind. But i was unsuccessful

```
output <- rbind(report_name , correlation)
```

Any pointers to this will be helpful. thank you.

Comment: there are _many_ "table" output packages for R data frames. did you do even a cursory Google search?

Comment: What is that? R is not a text processor. R is a number cruncher (not only).

Comment: [rmarkdown](http://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/). [knitr](http://yihui.name/knitr/). [`help(message)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/message.html). [`help(cat)`](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/cat.html).

Comment: @jogo - I am sorry. But i just wanted to see if there is any option available.

Comment: @hrbrmstr -  Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Though I'm not sure why you would want to do this, you could have both as elements of a list. As an example:

```
report <- list()
report[[1]] <- "Report Name"
report[[2]] <- head(mtcars)
```

Would return

```
report
[[1]]
[1] "Report Name"

[[2]]
                   mpg cyl disp  hp drat    wt  qsec vs am gear carb
Mazda RX4         21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.620 16.46  0  1    4    4
Mazda RX4 Wag     21.0   6  160 110 3.90 2.875 17.02  0  1    4    4
Datsun 710        22.8   4  108  93 3.85 2.320 18.61  1  1    4    1
Hornet 4 Drive    21.4   6  258 110 3.08 3.215 19.44  1  0    3    1
Hornet Sportabout 18.7   8  360 175 3.15 3.440 17.02  0  0    3    2
Valiant           18.1   6  225 105 2.76 3.460 20.22  1  0    3    1
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback @jogo. Could you suggest an alternative? I'm sure the OP would appreciate multiple solutions. To me, the question was asking how to package together a string a data frame, and I answered to the best of my knowledge.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 2):

If you do it within an r markdown document, it could look like this:

````
```{r}
kable(mtcars, caption = "Report Name")

```
````

Answer (score 0):

I interpret the question as: "how can I associate descriptive text with a data frame, so that there is more information that merely its name?"

The simplest way to do this

```
> data(cars)
> comment(cars) <- "Example Data"
> comment(cars)
```

[1] "Example Data

I wrote about more elaborate ways at http://rpubs.com/technocrat/metadata